# Differences in answers concerning the Sum of this AP.

Tags: sequences-and-series

"If S<sub>n</sub> = **a + bn + cn<sup>2</sup>**, find the nth term and nature of the series".
By using integral values of n , I realised it was an Arithmetic Progression with common difference 2c.
So using the formula to find the nth term as A<sub>n</sub> = S<sub>n</sub> - S<sub>n-1</sub> I got **b + c(2n-1)** as the solution, however when i use the formula A<sub>n</sub> = A<sub>1</sub> + (n-1)d , you get the answer as **a + b + c(2n-1)**.
I'd really appreciate it if someone told me why there is a difference in the answer when we use two different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange some terms of $S_n = a + bn + cn^2$ to get $S_n = a + \frac{n}{2}(2(b+c) + (n-1)2c)$. As you can see the part $\frac{n}{2}(2(b+c) + (n-1)2c)$ is the familiar formula for the sum of n terms of an arithmetic series with $T_1 = b+c$ and $d = 2c$. But there is also another $a$ in our formula so it cannot be an arithmetic series. If you try to find the terms you would get $(a+b+c), (b+3c), (b+5c), \dots$ and so on, which seems to be an AP apart from the first term.

Comment: Thanks for answering , I understood where i went wrong.